# How to create module wise jar in Ant build?

Tags: web-applications, ant, build, jar, war

I have developed web application. I want to create module wise jar. After creating module wise jar i want to create WAR with all JSP, images, css and lib(all jar).

Below my application structure

[image: Web Application Structure]

I want to create module1.jar,module2.jar, module3.jar and common_module.jar and include all following file jsp,images,css and finally create WAR.

Please help me ASAP...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create module1.jar..module2.jar..module3.jar. you need to create separate java project or module and create the jar..then you can build the WAR ..based on those( module jars) dependencies. you can use maven to manage the module dependencies and build the WAR.